# Excluding Values

Tags: count, conditional-statements

Currently I have a query with the following inputs,

[current query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlMlX.png)

I want to count the total amount of [weld_status] that go through each individual DAY per MONTH, but I want to exclude every input from [weld_status] that has a value of 4,

this is my current output with the follow script:

```
SELECT DAY(timestamp) as 'day', COUNT(weld_status) as 'COUNT'
FROM vw_rewelds_all
WHERE MONTH(timestamp) = MONTH(curdate())
and YEAR(timestamp) = YEAR(curdate()) 
group by DAY(timestamp);
```

[Output with current scrip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMTBz.png)

for example the total amount inputs I have for Day 19 is 51 when in reality it suppose to be 46 because i have 5 inputs containing the value of 4.

Comment: Please tag with the language you're using, like which kind of SQL / database is it for?

Comment: Which dbms is this???

Comment: **Like @B.Go Said, please tag what language you are using.**